# How can I enter an e-mail address with a comma in it into a cell?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to insert an email address with a comma in it (and it has to be entered that way) and I'm currently stumped on how to properly insert the exact text into this cell.

The e-mail address that needs to be entered as/is:

`joe,.E.Blow@someemail.com`

What I've tried is work different escape patterns into the code.  For example,  this...

`'''joe'''+','+'''.E.Blow@someemail.com'''`

gets entered into the database as...

`'joe','E.Blow@someemail.com'`

I've tried different combinations with single and double quotes and it can't even get past a simple parse without errors.

What is the best way to go about getting the email address entered as noted above?  I know it's something simple but I'm just spinning my wheels here.

Comment: Where are you concatenating the string?  Somewhere in SQL Server or in a programming language before it's passed to SQL Server?

Comment: where are you trying to insert the data from?  A direct `INSERT` statement works -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/625bf/1

Comment: I'm just doing a string of T-SQL INSERT statements with the SEQUENCE command from a script.

Comment: @TechieJoe can you post the full code that you are running?

Comment: This is not the full code but it gets the point across.  Again this is SQL 2012 I'm working with.

    INSERT INTO schema.tablename ([line_number], [EMAIL) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR schema.sequencename, 'joe\,.E.Blow@someemail.com')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is simple:

for example: `joe,.E.Blow@someemail.com`

SEE [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0c6ab/1)

Comment: Do you mean instead of a single quote use the slash?

Comment: near the comma use slash, for example: `INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('joe\,.E.Blow@someemail.com');`

Comment: Ok I modified the INSERT statement to:  

'joe\,.E.Blow@someemail.com'  

and it appears in the database as:  

joe\,.E.Blow@someemail.com  

If I enter without the quotes I get an 'Incorrect syntax' error.

Comment: Gil Peretz and bluefeet both provided the correct answer!  Cheers!